# Ensuring item count in observable stream

Tags: rx-java2

I have an unreliable data source. I ask for 20 data items from it and it 
might return:

- 20 items
- 1-20 items
- 0 items (there will be no more items from that data source ever)

I want to create a data provider that ensures that if I request 20 items I will always get 20 items by doing multiple requests to data source if needed.

So if I get 14 and then 11 items I need to cache those remaining 5 items for next request if there is one.

This class implementing this interface should handle all the logic I mentioned here.

```
interface GuaranteedDataPrivider {
  fun getData(itemCount : Int) : Single<List<Data>>
}
```

How one should go about doing that?

Comment: "next request if there is one" -- you imply that you are using a `Single`, so there can't be more than one request.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I think the cache has to support synchronous read so that it can satisfy requests for fewer items than are cached without sending another request. Sadly, that eliminates backpressure, which would otherwise be a very idiomatic way to go about this.

Comment: @BobDalgleish what I meant by that, that client show interested in data should (at least I think it should) receive it as `Single`. Or should it be `Observable` to indicate end of data by calling `onComplete` when there is no more data?

Comment: @concat for simplicity sake, lets say, that `requested_item_count` is a constant per such data provider instance.